# Application crashes on loading too many images in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, crash

I am creating an application which is loading 56 images of total size approximately 200MB, and when i am showing all these images in UIScrollView, application is taking too long time ( around 6 mins) and sometimes crashes.

Please suggest me a way to sort it out using UIView and loading 1 Image at a time. Images are saved within application.

Comment: What is your ImageView size ?

Comment: Actually application is similar to that of photo Library App of iPhone. And i am using 200 Image views of size 320X416 to populate them with images..

Comment: Then you need to lazy loading concept .... See H2CO3 answer !!

Answer (score 1):

If your imageview size is 320*416 pixels, then calculative memory size could be 320*416*200/1000000 = ~27 MB.

The better option is to scale image to 320 *416 pixels:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize;

- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor &lt; heightFactor) 
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor &lt; heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        } else if (widthFactor &gt; heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }


    // this is actually the interesting part:

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


    return newImage ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading that many images in a UIScrollView is very bad practice. Whenever you are handling this much content, you should think about using UITableViews or a library built to handle loading images in this fashion.

I actually wrote an iOS gallery a while back, FGallery, which you can find [here](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone).

Even with background threading, loading 56 images into memory at once when your application is only showing one, is not good. This leads to crashes, lockups, and an overall poor user experience. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to implement NSOperationQueue for preloading images and set to it number of the images it's first part. In NSOperationQueue you should setMaxNumberOfConcurenceOperations to a small number.

Next step - you should optimize your images!

If you have 56 images with 200MB approximately, then size of one your image is more than 3 MB. You should use graphic functions to create thumbnails for your images. The generated thumbnails should be less than 100KB. Store all images in File system.

And the last one, it's better not to store all UIImageViews in memory.  Instead, make use of an on-demand loading technique like what is used in UITableView.

Comment: I am showing images in full Mode, as a presentation View, to be displayed in whole screen . .And Swipe Action is been used to View Next/Previous Image . .

Comment: Okay Bhardwaj, then you should conain in memory only 3 sibling images. Previous, current and next. If you are using UIScrollView with pagenation then you should add delegate method on endDecelerating. In this method you should upload next image from file and UIImageView as Subview to your UIScrollView.